# Why 'corner' in the idiom 'Round the corner'?

Tags: etymology, idiom-requests

I know the idiom round the corner means very near. My question is, why round and corner? What is the connection between 'round' and 'corner'?

Comment: *'Round the corner* here means "around the corner".  Like the future, it is not yet visible.

Comment: And like "squaring the circle," the idiom is not as illogical as it may seem.

Answer (score 2):

Round the corner:
In close proximity to another location. Said especially when traveling by car, often when literally approaching a corner. The store isn't far from here, it's just around the corner.

Comment: And if it wasn’t around the corner, it might be *just down the road*.

Answer (score 0):

According to Etymologyonline
(https://www.etymonline.com/):

''***corner*** (n.)

late 13c., 
"place where streets or walls meet".''

In the idiom 'the corner' means the corner of the building or the streets which can be reached very easily and quickly on foot.

The idiom is used when you mean any place in the nearest neighborhood.

The idea of '***around the corner***' as something very close to the speaker or writer is extended in another idiom - 'To be just around the corner'.

It's been used in the sense "about to happen" since 1905 
(from:  https://www.etymonline.com/).

Comment: Perhaps the perception of this varies by locale, but in my mind the *corner* refers to the *street corner*. If you tell me there's a grill *around the corner* I'm going to assume it's a barbecue restaurant on the next street and not something in your backyard, unless you've specifically indicated a specific corner within the house.